# MacTeX 2015: Font installation fails

Tags: fonts, mactex

After upgrading TL on GNU/Linux in recent years I used to install my fonts located in $TEXMFHOME with the following one-liner:

```
for i in `find texmf/ -type f -name \*.map`; do base=`basename $i`; updmap --enable Map $base; done
```

This also worked on MacTeX 2014 (after cd'ing to Library). But it fails on MacTeX 2015, even with updmap-sys:

```
$ updmap-sys --enable Map=MinionPro.map
    updmap will read the following updmap.cfg files (in precedence order):
      /Users/chris/Library/texlive/2015/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg
      /usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg
      /usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg
    updmap may write changes to the following updmap.cfg file:
      /Users/chris/Library/texlive/2015/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg
    /Users/chris/Library/texlive/2015/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg unchanged.  Map files not recreated.
    updmap: Updating ls-R files.
```

(updmap instead of updmap-sys results in the same output)

I've updated the filename databases countless times. kpsewhich finds the corresponding map files. For example:

```
$ kpsewhich MinionPro.map
/Users/chris/Library/texmf/fonts/map/dvips/MinionPro/MinionPro.map
```

But running pdflatex results in:

```
kpathsea: Running mktexmf MinionPro-Bold-
! I can't find file `MinionPro-Bold-'.
```

…

```
! Font T1/MinionPro-OsF/b/n/10.95=MinionPro-Bold- at 10.95pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.
```

I called each of the commands with `sudo` and `sudo -H`. But it did not help. I'm at a loss.

Comment: The error message suggests a bad entry in a map file. Unrelated, but you should consider using the TEXMFLOCAL tree.

Comment: But I can't find “MinionPro-Bold-” in MinionPro.map … And the same map files worked with MacTeX 2014. What should I do?

Comment: Oh, sorry, in a `.fd` file. But it might also be a bad reference in one of the `.vf` (virtual font) files.

Comment: No match in any MinionPro related fd or vf files. I guess, I use those files for about ten years now. They did stop working by upgrading from MacTeX 2014 to MacTeX 2015.